# Как корректно получать переменные методом GET в PHP?

Tags: php, переменные, get

Доброго времени суток, иногда бывает нужен именно GET метод, приведу кусочек кода:

```
$pags = '0'; // количество найденного товара
$ipage = '15'; // позиций на страницу
$nowpage = '1'; // страница которая сейчас

if ($_GET) {
$ipage=$_GET['itm'];
$nowpage=$_GET['pg'];
$pags=$_GET['pags'];
}
```

Когда в адресной строке заданны все переменные или не одной, то работает корретно, а когда скажем только одна то вылетает ошибка.

**- как корректно с точки зрения кода и безопасности получить данные?**

**- будет ли работать ваш метод для POST?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[isset](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php)

Comment: if(isset($_GET['itm'])) $ipage=$_GET['itm'];
if(isset($_GET['pg'])) $nowpage=$_GET['pg'];

спасибо огромное такой код работает корректно!

Answer (score 2):

> if(isset($_GET['itm'])) $ipage=$_GET['itm'];

я обычно так делаю:

```
$ipage = isset($_GET['itm']) ? $_GET['itm'] : "1";
$page  = isset($_GET['pg']) ? (int)$_GET['pg'] : 1; // если это число
```

для POST все аналогично

Answer (score 0):

Сточки зрения безопасности рекомендую использовать **filter_input**, там Вам и проверка и значение по умолчанию

```
$options=array('options'=>array('default'=>0, 'min_range'=>0, 'max_range'=>999));
$pags=filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pags', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options);
```

[Подробнее на php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-input.php)